# How to install FireBird on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, database

I would like intall FireBird on ubuntu 12.04 32bit. 
I've downloaded it from [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5-2-upd1/#Linux_x86).

There is a `.rpm` file in `~/Downloads/FirebirdSS-2.5.2.26540-0.i686.rpm`.

I've seen [this link](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg2-installing.html) for how to install it, But i don't understand !

What i must to do with that `.rpm` file ? tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rpm is a package type used by Red Hat/Fedora. It is possible to install rpm packages in Ubuntu but I don't recommend it as I had bad experiences doing that.

Firebird is already in the Ubuntu repository, you don't have to download it and install it by yourself. Just open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run:

```
sudo apt-get install firebird2.5-super
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you read [this](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/ubusetup.html)?

It doesn't look like you need the `.rpm` file, running:

`sudo apt-get install firebird2.1-super` from a terminal should install FireBird.  The link I gave provides details on further configuration as well.

Comment: @george: Have a look at the original and the proposed edit.  The Original author clearly wanted to use the standard repository whereas the edit proposes a PPA.  This clearly conflicts with the original author's intent.  Please don't robo-review.

Answer (score 1):

First, install Alien. Alien is a utility that converts .rpm to .deb files.

`sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential`

Navigate to your downloads directory with the following command:

`cd ~/Downloads`

Run alien on your Firebird package:

`sudo alien FirebirdSS-2.5.2.26540-0.i686.rpm`

Install the new deb file with `dpkg`

`sudo dpkg -i FirebirdSS-2.5.2.26540-0.i686.deb`